# Cannot use console method. How can I use it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception

I am practicing how to code using the IntelliJ Idea JAVA  Editor.

I am trying to use the console method example:

`System.console().printf("Hello World');`
OR
`System.console().readLine("Good Morning);`

but for some reason I keep getting a error.
How can I make it work using the console method?

[image]

Comment: It's better if you paste the error and the line it is referring to instead of a screen shot. Help us help you. What code does the line with the exception has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `System.console()` like that, instead

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

**or**

```
System.out.printf("%s%n", "Hello World");
```

And to read from `System.in`, I would suggest a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html); like

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a line: ");
String line = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("You entered: " + line);
```

The reason I would avoid [`System.console()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) is documented in the Javadoc which notes *whether a virtual machine has a console is dependent upon the underlying platform and also upon the manner in which the virtual machine is invoked.*

```
Console cons = System.console();
if (cons != null) {
    String line = cons.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);
} else {
    System.out.println("no console");
}
```

And in my IDE (as in yours), there is no `System.console()`